# Kion signifas "herniulo"?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

> ...nek ĝibulo, nek ftizulo, nek makulokululo, nek aknulo, nek favulo,
>   nek **herniulo**... (Levidoj 21:20)

Kion signifas "herniulo"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La vorto "herniulo" signifas "persono kun hernio".